# mypy dont works on all scopes level?

Tags: python, mypy

I have a question about mypy (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

If i write this code:

```
class MyClass:
    def show(self) -> str:
        return 'Correctly'


class MyOtherClass:
    def show(self) -> str:
        return 'Wrong'


def foo(instance: MyClass) -> None:
    print(instance.show())


foo(MyClass())  # mypy ok
foo(MyOtherClass())  # mypy fails
```

and check it by mypy, i see error

`error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "MyOtherClass"; expected "MyClass"  [arg-type]`

in this case mypy help me understand what is wrong and says about it.

Okay.

If i edit above code to this:

```
class MyClass:
    def show(self) -> str:
        return 'Correctly'


class MyOtherClass:
    def show(self) -> str:
        return 'Wrong'


def foo(instance: MyClass) -> None:
    print(instance.show())


def start():
    foo(MyClass())  # mypy ok
    foo(MyOtherClass())  # mypy ok


start()
```

and check it by mypy, it will be no errors found:

`Success: no issues found in 1 source file`

And i'm confused...
Why mypy dont see error in second example?
We can force mypy see error in second example?

What's the point of using mypy if it doesn't work on "all levels"?

Maybe i dont understand anything?
Thanks for your attention.

I took a quick look at the documentation but didn't find anything about this.

Comment: Please ignore `__init__` mention in the linked dupe, it's true for any function or method - bodies of unannotated functions are not typechecked unless you enable `--check-untyped-defs`